# how to get ppbValue information from SLGetWindowsInformation from c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Presently i am getting the output for "pcbValue" and "peDataType" but not understanding how to get the value for "ppbValue"

Following is the code I am trying:

```
ULONG Type = 0;
SLDATATYPE DataType;
UINT value = 0;
PBYTE  ValuePtr = 0;

HRESULT status = SLGetWindowsInformation(L"Microsoft-Windows-DOT11PREF-AllowAdhoc",
    &DataType, &value, &ValuePtr);

if (status == S_OK) {

    cout << "DataType = " << DataType << endl;
    cout << "value = " << value << endl;
    cout << "ValuePtr = " << ValuePtr << endl;
}else {
    printf("File could not be opened.\n Error = %x", status);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965834.aspx). It would be wise to read it once again, to make sure you did not miss anything first time.

The documentation explains how to find out the type of data contained in the byte array that is returned. Namely by inspecting the value of the [`SLDATATYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965831.aspx) that is returned.

That enumeration is defined likewise:

```
typedef enum _tagSLDATATYPE { 
  SL_DATA_NONE      = REG_NONE,
  SL_DATA_SZ        = REG_SZ,
  SL_DATA_DWORD     = REG_DWORD,
  SL_DATA_BINARY    = REG_BINARY,
  SL_DATA_MULTI_SZ  = REG_MULTI_SZ,
  SL_DATA_SUM       = 100
} SLDATATYPE;
```

Given that you are asking for a specific named value, you know what type to expect. So, test that the returned value is the expected type, and cast the returned data to that type. Something like this:

```
SLDATATYPE eDataType = 0;
UINT cbValue = 0;
PBYTE pbValue = 0;

HRESULT status = SLGetWindowsInformation(L"Microsoft-Windows-DOT11PREF-AllowAdhoc",
    &eDataType, &cbValue, &pbValue);

if (status != S_OK) {
    // handle error
}
if (eDataType != SL_DATA_DWORD) {
    LocalFree(pbValue);
    // handle error
}

DWORD Value = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(pbValue);
LocalFree(pbValue);
```

Note that I am assuming that `SL_DATA_DWORD` is the correct type. I may be wrong. You presumably know what type is expected and can fill in the correct value. And obviously if the actual type is different, then your cast needs to reflect that too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am looking out for the type REG_SZ data type for this i am not getting the value.

Comment: I don't understand that comment

Comment: The eDataType type i am getting is SL_DATA_SZ so for that i need a value .when eDataType  is of SL_DATA_DWORD i am getting a proper value.

Comment: In that case you need to cast to `wchar_t*`. `std::wstring Value = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(pbValue);` I guess